# compiling an embedding python 3.5 in a visual 97 windows c program

Tags: python, c, compilation

I am trying to create a program using C and python. What I am attempting to do, is to create plots dynamically.
All the plot programs i've found require a file or some static source.  The python part I want to create will have an API that I will be able to use with any C program I wish to create.

An earler request helped me find the correct python libery (I needed to download python again). Thank you very much. I added the path to the library and now get a compile error.

I get an error of:

> C:\Python35\libs\python35_d.lib : fatal error LNK1106: invalid file or disk full: cannot seek to 0x5666a758

I am using Microsoft Developer Studio 97
the include directories are:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevStudio\VC\INCLUDE
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevStudio\VC\MFC\include
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevStudio\VC\ATL\include
C:\Python35\include
```

the library directories are:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevStudio\VC\LIB
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevStudio\VC\MFC\lib
C:\Python35\libs
```

the source directories are:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevStudio\VC\mfc\src
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevStudio\VC\mfc\include
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevStudio\VC\atl\include
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\DEVSTUDIO\SHAREDIDE\HELP
```

The program code is a example given in a python 3.5 tutorial:

```
#include "Python.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
wchar_t *program = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[0], NULL);
if (program == NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: cannot decode argv[0]\n");
    exit(1);
}
Py_SetProgramName(program);  /* optional but recommended */
Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                   "print('Today is', ctime(time()))\n");
Py_Finalize();
PyMem_RawFree(program);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: is the disk full?

Comment: I had to Google "Visual Studio 97" to even discover that such a product ever even existed and what version of VC++ it shipped with!  Why are you using such an antique when [Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/) is free and Microsoft have been providing free editions since VC++ 2005 Express, and free command line tools since 2003?

Comment: Why are MFC, and ATL at all relevant to this build?Your "source directories" list appear to be part of DevStudio - I am not sure it is relevant, but where are your sources?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to link a modern (possibly 64 bit?) library *python35_d.lib* using a tool-chain from 1997.  It is highly probable that the antique linker will not process the newer library file.

Update your tool-chain with the free [Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/) and enjoy the benefits of the 21st century!

Even with a newer tool chain you will need to make sure that the build type (64 or 32 bit) matched the library you are linking.